# Can't replace punctuation in Java string

Tags: java, android, string, replace

Here's my code:

```
public void storeWords(String sentence)
{
    String[] wordlist = sentence.split("\\s+");

    int stringLength = wordlist.length;
    for(int j = 0; j < stringLength; j++)
    {
        wordlist[j].replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z ]", "");
        System.out.println(wordlist[j]);
    }
}
```

So the for-loop right now is just to check if every word has the punctuation replaced. None do. I've also checked it on simply "sentence.replaceAll(.....)" and still not working. Any clue on where I'm going wrong?

`"If somebody falls and has no protection, do they get hurt?"`

returns

```
"If"
"somebody"
"falls"
"and"
"has"`
"no"
"protection, "
"do"
"they"
"get"
"hurt?"
```

Comment: What does replaceAll do, _exactly_?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strings are immutable, you have to do this:

```
wordlist[j] = wordlist[j].replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z ]", "");
```

(immutable means that they cannot be changed once assigned, so you need to make a new assignment in order to change the value of a String)

Comment: Gosh how do I always forget that. Sometimes, I wish I was using C or C++ again. Thanks! I'll accept it when my timer closes.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't assign the result of [replaceAll()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29), when I change it to this -

```
wordlist[j] = wordlist[j].replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z ]", "");
```

I get the output (with your input)

```
If
somebody
falls
and
has
no
protection
do
they
get
hurt
```

> Note the *Returns* from the Javadoc, is "The resulting String".